# Is there much overhead from compiling in mod_proxy?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I'm trying to keep my Apache installs as lean as possible, but I sometimes have the requirement to use mod_proxy. Does anyone know if there's much overhead from compiling mod_proxy into Apache rather than using a shared module when it's needed?

Answer (score 0):

The overhead is the other way around. There is a method-resolution step when loading a shared library, but it only happens once.

But I don't understand why you are even contemplating doing this if you think there's an overhead.